# WCF callback and non WCF client

Tags: wcf, wcf-callbacks

I wonder if you can use WCF callback with a client not implemented in .NET.  Google could not answer me for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 'can a non-WCF client app support WCF's duplex messaging capability?'

If so, then, of course it can - but you may have to build the client-side code yourself ... and doing so is unlikely to be a trivial task.

Question: Since Mono runs almost everywhere, can you not build your client app using Mono?